How to Prevent Style Overwrite in Vuetify 3 v-text-field When Embedded?
I'm using a v-text-field component in Vuetify 3, and it works fine until I embed my chatbot onto a website. When embedded, the website's styles overwrite my component's styles, affecting the height, background, and rounded corners of the input field. Additionally, a persistent black underline appears when focused.
Here's the relevant code:
<!-- Message input and send button -->
<div class="message-input-container">
  <v-text-field v-model="newMessage" label="Type a message..." class="message-input" @keydown.enter="sendMessage" ref="messageInput"></v-text-field>
  <v-btn icon class="send-button" @click="sendMessage">
    <v-icon>mdi-send</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</div>

CSS styles:
.message-input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 12px 8px 12px;
}

.message-input {
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.send-button {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 52px;
  padding: 0;
}

Here's how it should look (correct view):

Here's how it looks when embedded on the website (error view):

How can I ensure that my component retains its styles without being affected by the parent website's CSS?"
Update:
After modifying the message-input to have a gray background and rounded corners, a new issue arose.

Whenever the text field is focused, a white frame with sharp corners and shadows appears, and my efforts to hide it using the following CSS directives on the parent container have been unsuccessful:
.message-input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 12px 8px 12px; 
  box-shadow: none !important; /* Removes box shadows */
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; /* Removes box shadows for WebKit browsers */
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important; /* Removes box shadows for Mozilla browsers */
  outline: none !important; /* Removes focus outlines that might look like shadows */
  border: none !important; /* Removes borders that might give a shadow effect */
}

.message-input {
  height: 56px;
  max-height: 56px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0; /* Adjust bottom padding as needed */
  margin: 0 6px 0 0; /* Adjust bottom padding as needed */
}

This has not resolved the issue. How can I ensure that my component retains its intended styles and eliminate this unwanted focus effect when embedded within a different website’s environment?"
Update 2 on the Issue:
After further investigation, I found that this white frame with shadows appearing around the text field when focused is caused by the following CSS rule in the parent website's base.css:
*:focus-visible {
    outline: .2rem solid rgba(var(--color-foreground), .5);
    outline-offset: .3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .3rem rgb(var(--color-background)), 0 0 .5rem .4rem rgba(var(--color-foreground), .3);
}

I tried overriding these styles using the following CSS, but it didn't have any effect:
input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important; /* Removes box shadows */
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; /* For WebKit browsers */
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important; /* For Mozilla browsers */
}

.message-input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important; /* Removes box shadows */
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; /* For WebKit browsers */
  -moz-box-shadow: none ! important; /* For Mozilla browsers */
}

Despite these attempts, the unwanted focus effect persists. How can I effectively override these focus styles from the parent website's CSS?

Mostly a CSS specificity issue? I am not sure that you could overwrite it or maybe namespace your CSS? But trying to have an iframe is a good start IMO, that way you can probably keep your own thing intact when embedded somewhere.
